# Is it ok if light bulb touches metal bolt that secures globe?

Tags: electrical

I noticed the light bulb I am replacing is going to touch or is touching the metal bolt that secures the globe to the fixture.  Should I be concerned?

Comment: Pictures are always helpful so we can see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an incandescent bulb, then I'd either adjust things so it doesn't touch or get a smaller bulb.  I'm concerned that the bulb will heat up the metal parts presenting a burn hazard or the colder metal may caused the bulb to crack.

If this is an LED bulb, no worries.

Comment: Except some cheapo LEDs energize the metal case/heatsink of the LED bulb especially when fixtures are miswired... so that could be colorful.

Comment: Good point.  I'm sure I was thinking of LED bulbs from reputable manufacturers and that are UL listed.